# How to count the number of times a word appears in a webpage using javascript (in a Greasemonkey script)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, word-count

I'm a beginner in javascript and have no idea as to how to count the number of times a word appears in a webpage.

I've researched in different forums but got no help. I would really appreciate any suggestion or tips to achieve this functionality.

Comment: [count the words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_count)

Comment: i'm not sure that link helps. Also not sure why this got a -1

Answer (score 4):

Four things to be aware of if you want to use a Greasemonkey script to count instances of a word:

1. Use [the special `\b` character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary), in your regex to ensure that you actually get ***words***.
   For example, `/\bof\b/` matches "of" but not "offer".
2. Always check that `match()` results are not null before trying to access their properties!  `match(regex).length` will throw an exception much of the time.
3. Beware that careless **scripts can mutually interfere with the web page.**  This is part of why one of the other answers did not work.
   To avoid this, turn Greasemonkey's sandbox back on by specifying a `@grant` directive. GM scripts now default to `grant none` in many situations!
4. Beware that many sites, like Google, **load content via AJAX**, long after the Greasemonkey script fires.  There are many strategies to compensate for that.  Perhaps the most straightforward is to use a timer.

Putting it all together, here is **a complete script** that compensates for all of these issues.  You can also [**see the code in action at jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/TEGXC/):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Show word counts
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
$("body").append ('<div id="gmWordCount"></div>');

checkWordCount ();  //-- Initial run, works for static HTML only.

//--- Check for AJAX loaded words... Over twice a sec is plenty fast.
var wordChkTimer = setInterval (checkWordCount, 444);

function checkWordCount () {
    //--- Search for "of" as a whole word.
    var wordStr     = "of";
    var wordRegex   = new RegExp ("\\b" + wordStr + "\\b", "gi");
    var matchRez    = $(document.body).text ().match (wordRegex);
    var wordCount   = matchRez ? matchRez.length : 0;

    //--- Display the results.
    var countReport = '';
    switch (wordCount) {
        case 0:
            countReport = '"of" was not found!'
        break;
        case 1:
            countReport = '"of" was found one time.'
        break;
        default:
            countReport = '"of" was found ' + wordCount + ' times.'
        break;
    }

    //--- Display results to the user.
    $("#gmWordCount").text (countReport);
}

//--- Position and style the display output,
GM_addStyle ( "                                 \
    #gmWordCount {                              \
        background:         orange;             \
        position:           fixed;              \
        top:                0;                  \
        left:               0;                  \
        width:              100%;               \
        z-index:            6666;               \
    }                                           \
" );
```

Comment: Thanks for this, works well. I'm trying to modify to allow me to pass an array of words into the function and return the counts for each word, any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: @JeffSolomon, that's a bit more involved and needs to be a new question (one which has probably been asked before; so search thoroughly).  One tip:  This approach is not the best way to scale to an array, as it quickly would become CPU intensive with multiple `.match` passes through the page.  Can't easily say everything needed in comments (one of the reasons why that needs to be a new question).

Answer (score 1):

This is a start for you. As it stands it will match instances that exist inside other words, e.g. "coffee" will count for "of", it will interfere with other pages, I haven't checked if jQuery already exists. So you'll need to actually do some work yourself.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Count words
// @namespace   count
// @version     1
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$(function(){
    var word='of'; // put your word here
    var regex = new RegExp(word, "gi")
    alert ($('body').text().match(regex).length);
});
```

Comment: I tested ur script on google search's result(provided a random word). but could not get the output .. not even an alert box.

Comment: everything is better with jquery .. preferably with two version of it a once

Comment: This code will (1) crash many pages (JQ sandbox issue), (2) will throw exceptions if the word is not found, and (3) will count instances that are not the target word!

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = document.body.textContent
    .replace(/\r?\n?/g, "") // removes lines
    .replace(/\s{2,}/g, " "), // removes duplicate spaces
word = new RegExp("of", "gi");

alert(text.match(word).length);
```